# PHP Display no results on search

Tags: php, database, forms

I have a search that gets info from database. If there is no results I want form to say no results. Here is my code.

```
<?php 
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member
WHERE (`Name` LIKE '".$query."')") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0) while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) echo $results['Name'] 

?>
```

How do I add the no results via this code? I have tried adding this code to the end but it gives me an error.

```
    }
else{ 
    echo "No results";
}
```

Comment: What is the error? How are we supposed to help you without seeing the error message?

Comment: Did you forget the opening bracket (`{`)?

Comment: _Sidenote_: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection - read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Can I add this to stop SQL injection?    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

Comment: `WHERE ('Name' Like '%".$query."%')")`

Comment: @X_JuDaH_X You *could*, but it'd be best to go ahead and switch to parametrized PDO or mysqli, since mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP.

Comment: @aynber I need to study up on mysqli  Want to get this at least working than can tweak and change where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide you a general syntax:

```
$search_query = "select * from search_table where fname like '%$var%'";

if (! $con_query= mysql_query( $search_query, $con) )
                echo mysql_error(); 

$count_result = mysql_num_rows($con_query);

if( $count_result > 0 )
{       
     while ($search_data = mysql_fetch_array($con_query))   
     {
      echo $search_data['lname'];
     }
}
else
{
   echo "No record found.";
}
```

Comment: This gives me No record found but if it sees a record it gives me a record and still the error message no record found.

Comment: You must have records in your data base

Comment: I do have records..When I search for name and it comes up it gives me data from that name but still the error No Records found come up.

Comment: If you search for a valid record, it provide you the correct records or not ?

Comment: Yes it provides me with correct records but still says no record found